# Is there a way to skip a specific CSS selector in HTML when using querySelector in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I need to skip this `querySelector('input')` because in certain instances the input will come second instead of first. Is there a way to label an element in HTML as 'skip this'?

Comment: Yes, use `:not([selector])` to exclude whatever element you need

Comment: You can use `$("input:not(.skip-this)` or `$("input").not(".skip-this")` but it would be easier if you provided some html or could detail how you would identify which input to skip.

Comment: Typically inputs have names, at least it is recommended, so perhaps it would be a lot easier for you to target the name attribute instead `document.querySelector('input[name="theInputName"]')` ...

Answer (score 1):

You're free to utilize the full power of CSS syntax there. In your example if you only want to get input if it's the first parent's element then query like this:

`querySelector('input:first-child');`

Or if you want to get precise use `:nth-child` selector, or even better, `:nth-of-type`:

`querySelector('input:nth-of-type(1)');`

But the best solution would be to mark your input with a class or id and use it instead:

`querySelector('.myInput');`

You can of course combine it with negation selector:

`querySelector('.myInput:not(':nth-child(2)')');`

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` returns the first Element that matches the selector provided in the method. And why wouldn't it? That's what it's supposed to do.

A.E. the below returns the first input tag it can find on the document from the top-down.

```
document.querySelector("input");
```

It will **always** return the first input tag it can find. You have two options to "*skip*" the node. You can either write a function to recursively check if the input should be skipped( *kind of superfluous and bad looking* ) or you can simply be more specific with your selector.

Either way you need to give the input element you want to skip some sort of recognizable trait. That can be a `name` property or a `dataset` property or a `class` or an `id` - *anything* that you can programatically check for.

```js
//functional example
function ignoreSkippable() {
let ele, eles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input"));
eles.some(elem => !elem.matches('.skippable') ? ele = elem : false);
return ele;
}
console.log( ignoreSkippable() );
// <input value="second input"></input>


//specific selector example
let ele = document.querySelector("input:not(.skippable)"); 
console.log(ele); // <input value="second input"></input>
```

```html
<input class="skippable" />
<input value="second input" />
```